# Laravel groupBy rank resulting in multiple grouped rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, laravel-4, ranking

I'm using the `groupby()` function on my query to get some stats on two groups of athletes.

I have a table with my athletes and one with their performance.

```
- athletes table
-- id
-- name
-- group_id

-performance table
-- id
-- DateTime
-- athlete_id
-- sport_id
-- time
```

Each athlete do the same sport for multiples days (which is not the same for all athletes). **I would like to see the evolution of the `time average` over days per group in a given sport.**

I run this query

```
$query = '*, AVG(time) as average_time' ;
$Performance = Performance::join('athletes','performance.athlete_id','=','athletes.id')
                            ->select(\DB::raw($query))
                            ->where('performance.sport_id', '=', '43')
                            ->orderBy('group_id', 'asc')
                            ->groupBy('group_id')
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();
```

However, this give me the average for a given sport_id but not over each days.

How can I see the average for **every day** in a given sport `groupby group_id`?

Answer (score 0):

If DateTime is a timestamp then you can use the mysql date functions. Specifically GROUP BY WEEKDAY(timestamp_field).

Added into your query it looks like this

```
$query = '*, AVG(time) as average_time' ;
$Performance = Performance::join('athletes','performance.athlete_id','=','athletes.id')
                            ->select(\DB::raw($query))
                            ->where('performance.sport_id', '=', '43')
                            ->orderBy('group_id', 'asc')
                            ->groupBy('WEEKDAY(DateTime)')
                            ->groupBy('group_id')
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();
```